# Como verificar se um checkbox está checado com PHP?

Tags: php

Como verificar se um checkbox está checado, em um submit de formulário?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Se sua página HTML estiver dessa forma:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="meucheckbox" value="umvalorqualquer">
```

Ao ser enviado, se o check box não estiver marcado, não existirá a variável **meucheckbox**, o valor dele é **NULL**. Caso esteja marcado ele recebe a variável **meucheckbox** e o seu valor será **umvalorqualquer**.

Na página PHP você pode verificar da seguinte maneira caso o formulário seja submetido via POST:

```
if(isset($_POST['meucheckbox']))
{
    echo "checkbox marcado! <br/>";
    echo "valor: " . $_POST['meucheckbox'];
}
else
{
    echo "checkbox não marcado! <br/>";
}
```

Se o formulário for submetido via GET:

```
if(isset($_GET['meucheckbox']))
{
    echo "checkbox marcado! <br/>";
    echo "valor: " . $_GET['meucheckbox'];
}
else
{
    echo "checkbox não marcado! <br/>";
}
```

Se o checkbox estiver marcado, o resultado será:

```
checkbox marcado!
valor: umvalorqualquer
```

Se o checkbox não estiver marcado, o resultado será:

```
checkbox não marcado!
```

Answer (score 11):

Um `checkbox` em um formulário HTML só é enviado caso esteja marcado, então basta verificar se mesmo está presente nas variáveis `$_GET` ou `$_POST`.

Exemplo com método `post`:

```php
isset($_POST['minhacheck'])
```

Exemplo com método `get`:

```php
isset($_GET['minhacheck'])
```

No caso, o HTML seria:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="minhacheck" value="valor">
```

Comment: Obrigado utluiz, estava com dúvida se ele envia mesmo não estando marcado, tirou minha dúvida grato!

Answer (score 7):

```
  //Aqui verifico se o post do checkbox me retorna um valor verdadeiro ou falso (true ou false)
  $checkbox = $_POST["CheckBox"] ? "Marcado (true)" : "Desmarcado (false)";
  echo $checkbox; // Imprimo a resposta.
```

Comment: Hiago, se possivel desenvolva a resposta adicionando um comentário ao seu código e sobre porque este código resolve o problema.

Comment: Obrigado Sergio, comentei o código desculpe pela falta de atenção.

Comment: Óptimo! +1, assim fica bem mais útil para quem não consegue ler o que o código faz.

Answer (score 5):

Uma coisa que pode ter também que não vi é caso você não passe nenhum valor, por exemplo:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="meu_checkbox" checked="checked">
```

por exemplo, se enviar por post, no php irá pegar assim

```
if (isset($_POST['meu_checkbox']) && $_POST['meu_checkbox'] == 'on')
{
    echo "Meu Checkbox está marcado";
}
```

Você precisa verificar se existe o valor porque se o usuário não marcar o checkbox não irá ser passado nada e com isso irá te dar um erro, e quando não se passa nenhum valor é passado com valor `on`

O erro que irá dar caso não verifique se existe (isset) é esse:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: meu_checkbox

Answer (score 3):

No array de `$_REQUEST` (não sei se o método do seu formulário é `GET` ou `POST`), basta verificar se a chave do nome do seu checkbox está lá, com o valor correspondente.

Comment: ele só envia quando está checado?

Comment: Creio que seja interessante você postar o código com do seu formulário para podermos lhe ajudar melhor.

Comment: Isso mesmo, o valor só é enviado quando está marcado. O que você pode fazer é dar ao checkbox o nome de `checkboxes[]` (por exemplo) e ver os valores que estarão dentro do array `checkboxes` nos valores do `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: `$_REQUEST` sequer deveria existir. Se é POST, `$_POST`. Se é GET, `$_GET`. Se é COOKIE, `$_COOKIE`. Não só é errado usá-lo como em fazendo-o engessa a aplicação impedindo-a de reutilizar uma mesma palavra-chave de identificação no superglobal para cenários distintos.

Comment: Eu dei o exemplo com `$_REQUEST` pois não sabia que a pessoa estava usando GET ou POST. De fato deve-se pegar as variáveis com `$_GET` ou `$_POST`, respectivamente.

Comment: Sim, sim, só comentei para reforçar.

Answer (score 3):

A grande sacada é no formulario nomear as checkbox como vetor, conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
<table border="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td class="menu" width="130">
Treinamentos:
</td>
<td class="menu">
<nobr><input type="checkbox" name="ckbTreinamentos[]" value="I"> Internet</nobr>
</td>
<td class="menu">
<nobr><input type="checkbox" name="ckbTreinamentos[]" value="U"> URA</nobr>
</td>
<td class="menu">
<nobr><input type="checkbox" name="ckbTreinamentos[]" value="P"> POS</nobr>
</td>
<td class="menu">
<nobr><input type="checkbox" name="ckbTreinamentos[]" value="T"> TEF</nobr>
</td>
<td class="menu">
<nobr><input type="checkbox" name="ckbTreinamentos[]" value="C"> Celular</nobr>
</td>
<td class="menu">
<nobr><input type="checkbox" name="ckbTreinamentos[]" value="F"> Fechamentos</nobr>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Dai na hora do $_REQUEST[''] tu consegue montar um foreach que poderá ser jogado numa string, conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['ckbTreinamentos'])) {          
        $qt = count($_REQUEST['ckbTreinamentos']);
        $k = 1;         
        foreach ($_REQUEST['ckbTreinamentos'] as $treinamento){             
            $v = "";
            if($k < $qt) {
                $v = ", ";
            }
            $comp .= $treinamento.$v;
            $k++;
        }
        return $comp;
    } else {
        $comp = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Trabalhar com *checkbox* com PHP é bastante chato por causa dessa limitação de o programa receber o valor apenas se tiver sido marcado.

Mas essa limitação só se torna perceptivelmente irritante quando se tem muitos *checkboxes* num mesmo formulário, como por exemplo num editor de permissões de controle de acesso de usuário, onde seria preciso repetir dezenas de vezes um ternário ou criar uma verificação em loop a fim de simplificar o processo ao custo de ganhar [complexidade ciclomática](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexidade_ciclom%C3%A1tica)

Enfim... Para esses casos bem específicos você pode modificar o HTML definindo um campo do tipo *hidden* de mesmo nome do checkbox:

```
<input type="hidden" name="meucheckbox" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="meucheckbox" value="1" />
```

Dado o processamento vertical, se o checkbox não for marcado, ainda assim você terá, por exemplo, um `$_POST['meucheckbox']` de valor 0 (zero) e, caso seja marcado, a entrada será substituída no superglobal pelo valor devido.

Answer (score 1):

Se em seu formulário, você tiver por exemplo:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="status" value="ativo">
```

Ao submeter o formulário, se o campo NÃO estiver marcado, ele não será enviado para o seu servidor.

Logo seria como você tentar acessar um índice em um array sem que ele exista ou acessar um nome de índice em um array associativo inexistente.

Se ele estiver marcado você poderá acessar seu valor normalmente como em um array.

Na página PHP que receberá os dados enviados pelo formulário:

Poderá ser utilizado as variáveis globais: 
$_POST, $_GET ou $_REQUEST;

```
<?php
   //Verificando se o "índice associativo 'status'" foi enviado pelo formulário 
   $statusRecebido = (isset($_REQUEST['status']))?$_REQUEST['status']:'inativo';

   //Se o checkbox foi marcado, virá o valor contido no seu atributo 'value', ou seja, 'ativo'. 
   //caso não venha será atribuído o valor 'inativo' por exemplo.

   echo $statusRecebido."<br/>";
```

Espero ter ajudado melhor na compreensão.