# Dúvidas para enviar dados via POST

Tags: php, mysql, html5, bootstrap-3

Olá, eu estou tentando enviar via $_POST alguns dados para validação e posterior inserção no banco, o que eu conseguia fazer em outro projeto da exata forma que estou tentando fazer agora, porém não estou conseguindo.

**Este é o código do meu Form:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        CADASTRAR USUÁRIO
    </div><br>

    <div id="filtros" style="padding-left: 20px">
        <a id="voltar_pagina" href="menu.php" class="btn btn-primary" title="Voltar ao início">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
        </a>
        <a id="voltar_lista" href="javascript:history.back()" class="btn btn-primary" title="Voltar">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>                        
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body">

        <form id="form_cad_usuario" data-toggle="validator" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="../config/usuario/processa_cad_usuario.php">

            <!--DADOS DO USUÁRIO-->
            <div class="page-header">
                <h4>Dados do Usuário</h4s>
                <hr>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">                 
                <label for="ativo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ativo</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input id="ativo" type="checkbox">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nome_usuario" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nome</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome_usuario" placeholder="Nome" data-error="Por favor, informe o nome completo para o usuário." required>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--DADOS DE ACESSO-->
            <div class="page-header">
                <h4>Dados de Acesso</h4>
                <hr>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="login_usuario" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Usuário</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login_usuario" placeholder="Usuário" data-error="Por favor, digite um nome para o usuário." required>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="senha_usuario" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Senha</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha_usuario" placeholder="Senha" data-error="Por favor, digite um senha para o usuário." required>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--DADOS DA  REGIONAL-->
            <div class="page-header">
                <h4>Regionais Permitidas</h4>
                <hr>
            </div>

            <?php
            $resultado = lista_regionais();

            while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) 
            {
                $id_regional = $registro['id'];
                $nome_regional = $registro['nome'];

            ?>

            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <label class="col-md-10" for="<?php echo"regional_$id_regional" ?>">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo"regionais[$id_regional]"; ?>" id="<?php echo"regional_$id_regional" ?>"> 
                                    <small><?php echo $nome_regional; ?></small>
                                </label>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php
            }
            ?>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button id="botao_salvar" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Salvar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Aqui está o script 'processa_cad_usuario.php':**

```
<?php
session_start();

include_once ('../../dao/usuario_dao.php');

$_SESSION['cadastro_inserido'] = null;

var_dump($_POST['nome_usuario']);

//cadastra_usuario($nome, $login, $senha, $permissao, $flag_ativo, $criado, $modificado);
```

Ao tentar acessar, por exemplo, **$_POST['nome_usuario']** o php me diz que tal índice não está definido e ao fazer o **var_dump()** me retorna Null. Alguma sugestão?

Adicionalmente eu gostaria de sanar uma dúvida extra. No final do form eu tenho alguns checkboxes com nomes de cidades que são gerados dinamicamente e eu gostaria de saber qual a maneira de passar todos que forem selecionados para a página que processa o cadastro e como eu devo inserir eles no banco de dados e qual estrutura usar. Isso tendo em mente que em algum ponto eu vou precisar deles para dar permissão ao usuário para acessar dados das cidades para as quais ele tem permissão. Agradeço imensamente à quem puder ajudar. Abraço à todos.

Answer (score 1):

Nos inputs dentro do formulário ao invés de colocar "id" coloque "name". Por exemplo:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="login_usuario" placeholder="Usuário" data-error="Por favor, digite um nome para o usuário." required>
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, Daniel. Era isso mesmo, eu achava que ao dar o submit os valores dos campos seriam buscadas através do id. Quando eu seleciono o checkbox e dou um var_dump() me retorna um String: "On", gostaria de uma orientação da melhor maneira de lidar com as checkbox das cidades para salvar na tabela do usuário e posteriormente dar permissões de visualização ao usuário baseado nessas cidades. Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Você pode nomear as checkbox como um vetor e em seguida você pode pegar os valores selecionados com um foreach. Nesta pergunta tá explicando bem, dá uma olhada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5675/como-verificar-se-um-checkbox-est%C3%A1-checado-com-php

Answer (score 0):

Apenas adicione o atributo "name" aos seus inputs com o mesmo valor do Id:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome_usuario" name="nome_usuario" ... >
```

O id neste seu caso, é usado para vincular o campo com o label e talvez para validações de javascript, mas ele não é enviado para o servidor. O correto é sempre usar o atributo "name" para pegar dados no servidor com POST.

Comment: OK, essa parte ficou clara pra mim. Quanto à questão de enviar via POST as cidades selecionadas alguma sugestão? Obrigado por responder.

Answer (score 0):

O PHP está correto em informar que não existe o índice 'nome_usuario'. Pois ao se trabalhar com formulários e php, ao utilizar tanto o método de requisição HTTP: [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.post.php) como o: [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.get.php), as informações  são enviadas pelo name que você atribuiu ao campo do seu formulário. Tanto o $_POST como o $_GET é um array associativo com todas as chaves e valores de informações enviadas.

É interessante utilizar tanto a propriedade id quanto a propriedade name, pois o php por padrão utiliza o name, já outras linguagens necessitam do id para manipular elementos como é o caso do CSS e JavaScript.

Assim para funcionamento correto e bom uso é recomendado que seu input fique semelhante a:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome_usuario" name="nome_usuario" placeholder="Nome" data-error="Por favor, informe o nome completo para o usuário." required>
```