# Salvar checkbox dentro de While Laravel

Tags: laravel

Gostaria de saber como faço pra salvar valores `checkbox` dentro de um `while`, o campo `comprar01` o `checkbox` que deve retornar `true` ou `false`.

Recebo através do `request()`:

```
$idproduto=$request->get('idproduto');
$qnt=$request->get('qnt'); 
$comprar01=$request->get('comprar01');
```

Faço o `while` no `controller` pra salvar no banco

```
$cont = 0;
while($cont < count($idproduto))
{
    $detalhe = new MapaCompraDet();
    $detalhe->idmapacompra = $dados->idmapacompra;
    $detalhe->idproduto = $idproduto[$cont];
    $detalhe->qnt = $qnt[$cont];     
    $detalhe->comprar01=$comprar01[$cont]; //aqui o problema
    $detalhe->save();
    $cont = $cont + 1;
```

***Erro:***

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Tentei isso**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
  $dados = MapaCompra::findOrFail($id);        
  $idproduto=$request->get('idproduto');
  for ($i=0; $i < count($idproduto) ; $i++) {
      $comprar01 = (isset($request['comprar01']))?$request['comprar01']:'inativo';
      dd($comprar01);
  }
```

Ele me traz no **dd** somente os marcados, quando nao marco ele não traz. Pesquisei aqui e vi que tenho que por indices nos checkbox antes de inserir, estou tentando.
Veja: https://cursos.alura.com.br/forum/topico-inserindo-valores-de-checkbox-no-banco-de-dados-44489

**MEU FORMULARIO TEM UM ARRAY**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**CODIGO**

```
  <tbody id="tbodyCotacao">
                    @foreach($detalhes as $detalhe)
                      <tr>
                        <!-- ITENS COTAÇÃO 01 -->
                       <td>
                         <input style=" width: 60px" class="form-control" type="number" min="0" name="entrega01[]" value="{{$detalhe->entrega01}}">
                       </td>
                       <td>
                          <input style=" width: 70px" class="form-control" type="text" name="marca01[]" value="{{$detalhe->marca01}}">
                       </td>
                       <td>
                         <input id="pqnt" type="hidden" name="qnt[]" value="{{$detalhe->qnt}}">
                         <input id="vrunit01" style=" width: 65px;text-align:center" class="form-control" type="text" name="vrunit01[]" value="{{number_format($detalhe->vrunit01, 2, ',', '.') }}" onblur="multiplicar();" onblur="formatar();">
                       </td>
                       <td>
                         <input id="subtotal01" style="text-align:right;width: 75px" class="form-control subtotal01" type="hidden" name="subtotal01[]" readonly onblur="calcular();">
                         <input  style="text-align:right;width: 75px" type="text" class="form-control subtotal01T" id="subtotal01T" value="{{number_format($detalhe->qnt*$detalhe->vrunit01, 2, ',', '.') }}" readonly>
                       <td style="text-align:center">
                           <input @if($detalhe->comprar01=='c') {!! 'checked="checked" ' !!}@endif type="checkbox"  name="comprar01[]" value="c">
                       </td></tr>
```

Comment: é complicado fazer isso com `checkbox`, porque o PHP na hora de trazer a informação só traz o que foi selecionado, se existir no meio `checkbox` sem seleção o seu `array` `$comprar01` é menor que os outros e com certeza vai dar o erro da pergunta. Eu usuaria um `<select>`.

Comment: Verdade, ele trouxe apenas os checkados, quando nao checkado da erro.

Comment: Como seria com select? Me da um exemplo por favor...

Comment: Em cada linha um combo  com duas opções e valor 0 e 1 com label não e sim

Comment: Entrendi, assim ficaria facil mesmo, porem meu campo esta pequeno para por um select, teria que ser um checkbox mesmo. Engraçado que no meu cadastro funcionou normal, nessa tela pra editar que esta dando esse erro.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como verificar se um checkbox está checado com PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5675/como-verificar-se-um-checkbox-est%c3%a1-checado-com-php)

Comment: Dá uma olhada nessa resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5716/54880 essa é sua solução, até indiquei a sua pergunta como duplicata

Comment: Bom dia Virgilio, eu ja tinha visto esses topicos, porem estou testando mas nao esta funcionando, ele pega apenas os primeiros itens da lista. EX: se tenho 3 linhas, marco a 3 ele pega a 1 entendeu. Estou tentando ajustar mas ainda nao consegui.

Comment: Você fez o que??? Poste seu html

Answer (score -1):

Faz assim, aplica um valor default:

```
$comprar01 = $request->get('comprar01', 0);
```

OU

```
$comprar01 = $request->has('comprar01') ? 1 : 0;
```

Em campos como 'active', que são boolean nas migrations, e no banco TINYINT, antes de salvar/atualizar eu faço o seguinte.

```
$request->merge(['active' => $request->has('active')]);
$model->update($request->all());
```

At-te;

Comment: Legal, Cau, pode detalhar pra mim por favor, essa parte do active? Primeiro eu pego pelo request $comprar01 = $request->get('comprar01', 0); e para colocar em um loop para salvar?

Comment: Tem que ver o que vem no teu campo. Pelo teu código presumo ser um número inteiro ($count)... Então tu podes fazer assim. $comprar01 = $request->get('comprar01', 0);  ... Ou seja, se o checkbox ta marcado, vai pegar o valor dele, se não tiver marcado vai pegar o 0 como default. Tu coloca o valor default de acordo com teu código... como quiseres.  OU tu podes utilizar o merge antes de salvar/atualizar teus dados como exemplifiquei acima.   Se tu não marca o valor do checkbox a request vem null.  Utilize os métodos has(), get('key', $default) e merge([]) da request para trabalhar teu código.

Comment: O exemplo que dei na resposta presumi que teu campo era true/false... to teu caso pode fazer assim também:  $comprar01 = $request->has('comprar01') ? $request->get('comprar01') : 0;

Comment: Agora se teus checkbox podem ser array tmb. Melhor é postar o formulário html.

Comment: Sim meus checkboxs sao array estao dentro de uma tabela dinamica, vou pastar....

Comment: Mano, teu problema não é tão simples. Tens que setar dinamicamente o atributo 'name' do checkbox de acordo com o detalhe. Caso contrário não vai conseguir ligar um campo ao outro. No foreach dos detalhes faça algo do tipo. name="comprar-{{ $detalhe->id }}" ... Ou algo do tipo. Daí poderá aplicar as técnicas de qual falei.

Comment: e eu sei, pensei que seria mais facil. Vou seguir o conselho do nosso amigo Cecilio coloar um combobox mesmo, testei e aqui e foi tranquilho, é uma pena ia ficar legal com ckeckbox. Valeu obrigado.

Comment: Se achas mais legal, faça com checkbox cara. Tenta e debugar o código... É simples... dd($request->all()) no controller e tu vê exatamente o que está vindo na request; e assim, saberá o que precisa ser feito.

Comment: eu debuguei, ele so traz o checkbox checado, se nao tiver checado nao traz nada

Comment: É assim que deve ser mesmo. Só vem os marcados... Mas tu tem os names dos que poderiam estar marcado....   No foreach tu vê...

$model->attribute = $request->get('checkbox' . $detalhe->id, $valor_unchecked);

ou

$model->attribute = $request->has('checkbox' . $detalhe->id') ? $request->get('checkbox' . $detalhe->id') : $default;

Fácil cara. É só buscar os names que deve ser...

Comment: vou tentar aqui e dou retorno